# Is there any open source load generators?

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

I would like to know if there is any open source load generator for stress testing. I am using JMeter script to run the test. I know there is one called flood.io but think it is not free. Can you please recommend me some option and documentation on how to use it properly? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, JMeter is open source, you can observe [source repositories](http://jmeter.apache.org/svnindex.html) so it matches your needs.

The point is where to run JMeter so you need to have your own [bare metal machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare-metal_server) (or normal desktop/laptop/virtual machine). If you're looking for an open-source operating system there is a wide range of [free and open source Linux distributions](https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.en.html), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/), [illumos](https://illumos.org/), etc.

If you don't have any machines and any money to invest into these machines there are some free cloud options like [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) or [Oracle Cloud Free Tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/), also some SaaS service providers offer free pricing plans, for example [BlazeMeter gives you 50 virtual users](https://www.blazemeter.com/pricing/), [LoadFocus gives you 20 concurrent users](https://loadfocus.com/pricing), etc.